# SSIS can't connect to DB during SQL Server agent

Tags: mysql, batch-file, ssis, odbc

Just for the record this happens for both the SQL Server agent and when running the package through a batch file.

If I open CMD and paste this:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn

dtexec.exe /f "\\local\it$\Application Development\.NET Projects\A_ReportingTool\DailyUpload_DEV\DailyUpload\DailyUpload_Client.dtsx"
PAUSE
```

It runs through the SSIS perfectly. But as soon as I paste the command into a batch file and run it it says `There was an error trying to establish an Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) connection with the database server`

This is exactly the same if I run the package through SQL Server agent.

Previously I was getting XML parsing issues, I sorted this by using all 32bit ODBC connectors. But now I get this. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you used a System DSN for your ODBC connection, and not a User DSN.